# Javascript - loop through an array for relationships

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to properly ask the question but basically, I have an array of relationship Ids(predecessorId and successorId) and I want to loop through it and get the successorId(s) based on a predecessorId I will be looking. But the tricky part is, I also want to get the successorId(s)' successorId(s) until there is no successors anymore. Below is the sample context I want to achieve:

```
var sampleArray = [
{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"02"
},{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"03"
},{
    "predecessorId":"02",
    "successorId":"04"
},{
    "predecessorId":"04",
    "successorId":"05"
},{
    "predecessorId":"06",
    "successorId":"07"
}]
```

If I want to get the TREE successors of predecessorId "01" based on the sample array, the return should be:

"02" - because it's the direct successor of "01"

"03" - because it's the direct successor of "01"

"04" - because it's the indirect successor of "01" but direct successor of "02"

"05" - because it's the indirect successor of "01" but direct successor of "04"

Let me know if my question is vague. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted

```js
var sampleArray = [
{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"02"
},{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"03"
},{
    "predecessorId":"02",
    "successorId":"04"
},{
    "predecessorId":"04",
    "successorId":"05"
},{
    "predecessorId":"06",
    "successorId":"07"
}]
let arrMap={}
sampleArray.forEach(itm=>{
arrMap[itm.predecessorId]?arrMap[itm.predecessorId].push(itm.successorId):arrMap[itm.predecessorId]=[itm.successorId]
})
let successor=[]
const findSuccessor=(arr)=>{
if(!arr)
return 
arr.forEach(val=>{
successor.push(val)
findSuccessor(arrMap[val])
})
}
findSuccessor(arrMap["01"])
console.log(successor.sort())
```

**Logic**: First make a Map of all `predecessorId` i.e `{"01":[],"02":[],"04":[],"06":[]}` that will store its `successorId` in an array.

Then recursively find all direct and indirect successors using `findSuccessor`

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Using `map()` just to loop array elements is not a good practice. `forEach` is a better tool to do that

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, next time onwards I'll keep that in mind. Updated answer with forEach. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of this:

```js
var sampleArray = [
{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"02"
},{
    "predecessorId":"01",
    "successorId":"03"
},{
    "predecessorId":"02",
    "successorId":"04"
},{
    "predecessorId":"04",
    "successorId":"05"
},{
    "predecessorId":"06",
    "successorId":"07"
}];

var pre_id = "01";
var result = [];

result = sampleArray.filter(x => x.predecessorId === pre_id)
                    .map(x => x.successorId);

for (var item of result) {
  var temp = sampleArray.filter(x => x.predecessorId === item);
  if (temp.length > 0) {
    result.push(temp[0].successorId);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

**Rule:** Getting `successorId` values based on `predecessorId`. Then, based on the result, making a loop to get another `successorId` from `sampleArray`